# WP_Query retrieve custom posts but not the post showing

Tags: posts, wp-query, query

I am developing a custom post type which shows releated posts which are within the category which is working perfect but I cant seem to get the right query to make it not show the current post which is being viewed.

The code I have at present is:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custompostname',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array( 
                'taxonomy' => 'custompostname-categories',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $categoryIDs
            )
        ),
        'post__not_in' => $post->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 20
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
```

Could anyone please shed some light on why this is not working.

If I remove the:

```
'post__not_in' => $post->ID,
```

It works apart from it shows the post which is on the page already

Thanks

Comment: I've had similar trouble once, did u try `'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID) ` instead ?

Comment: Yes its there please see :)

Comment: @webdwall sorry did not read it correctly, yes adding an array works :) thank you

Comment: No, i mean, instead of `'post__not_in'=>$post->ID`, did u try taking post id in an array, even though its just one. like `'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID)`

Comment: Ok, if it works then please mark the question as solved and you can upvote my comment as well if you want :)

Comment: @webdwall I cant upvote your answer because you did not submit an answer, can you submit and ill accept :)